# Oracle Apex Interactive Report bad performance while loading

Tags: performance, oracle-apex-5

I have an interactive report in one of my APEX application. The SQL query used in the IR runs pretty fine when executed in SQL Developer.

But, at times in the application it gets stuck and requires more time than usual to load the IR. (Usually it takes less than 5 secs to load but at times more than 50 secs).

What might be the possible reasons for it to load slow ?

The query is well tuned and IR has default settings with no modification. I have also checked the stats on the tables and it is fresh.

The SQL query used in IR fetches 10k records.

Comment: `@Superdooperhero`, `@Enrique`, `@Boris`, `@Kapiell`, `@TheDS` I'm facing the same problem. In my case a very complex sql query is used. it has 57 columns and it joins more 12 tables. even the size of sql query is about 30k characters in length. I've already optimized the query. On SQL developer if checked for 1 year data, this can load even 3M records in just 2-3 secs. Also, cost is below 500 as per `post execution plan` and below 50 as per `explain plan`. But on apex it is taking more than 10 minutes for a quarter. I'm using `apex 19.1`. I've tried all 3 reports.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into Component View and then click Interactive Report under Regions, there is a setting near the bottom under the Performance heading called Maximum Rows To Process. Also limiting the number of rows to display sped things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i can't write comments. Is there any database view in your query?
 
I have similar situation where query from database view with 6 mil. records take around 3 min to complete in Oracle Apex IR and 10-15 seconds in SQL Developer. So after some research i try to put sql from view directly into IR and result was almost same as this in SQL Developer. 
Also You can remove pagination from IR or change it from "x to y from z" to be only "x to y".
I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Query response time in SQL Developer versus any other Web browser cannot be compared directly. Some of the reasons for its slugishness could be related to server setup, server load, current user traffic, page load processes, page and region rendering, number of regions,components and plugins, navigation menu query, report query, number or columns and rows being displayed, row content length, apex items especially LOV with SQL queries, etc.

From your question, it looks like performance issue is not consistent and so, I think issue may be related to server setup or traffic. Try to check if you see any difference in load time after bouncing the server, if that's an option. Try to isolate the problem and if the issue is specific to interactive report, build a classic report and compare times.

Another thing that has helped me in past is to compare and verify compute times using APEX Debugger, here is the screenshot.

[image]

Also look at network and timeline tabs in Chrome debugger,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement indexes on your tables
2. Verify with your DBA if you have database locks
3. Verify the amount of logs in Database
4. Switch to classic reports.

Regards